# i'm trying to sanitize but it doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, database, next.js, xss, sanitize

i'm trying to sanitize html string before sending it into database, i'm using sanitize-html npm package but it doesn't work

```
if (noteContent) {
  const resultContent = sanitize(noteContent);
  console.log(resultContent);
} else {
  setErrorMessages((prevState) => ["note content cannot be empty"]);
}
```

here when i'm entering `<img src=? onerror="alert('hello')" />`
it returns:

```
<p><img src=? onerror="alert('hello')" /></p>
```

i don't get it what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation available on Github](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html?tab=readme-ov-file), the function you are looking for should be called `sanitizeHtml()` and not `sanitize()`

However, if you read closely, per default it does allow quite some html tags and attributes listed here: https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html?tab=readme-ov-file#default-options

In order to be more restrict, follow the example provided in their [documentation](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html?tab=readme-ov-file#node-recommended).

```js
// Allow only a super restricted set of tags and attributes
const clean = sanitizeHtml(dirty, {
  allowedTags: [ 'b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a' ],
  allowedAttributes: {
    'a': [ 'href' ]
  },
  allowedIframeHostnames: ['www.youtube.com']
});
```

For your example provided this would look something like this:

```js
if (noteContent) {
  const resultContent = sanitizeHtml(noteContent, {
    allowedTags: [], 
    allowedAttributes: {}
  });
  console.log(resultContent);
} else {
  setErrorMessages((prevState) => ["note content cannot be empty"]);
}
```

See also this part of the [documentation](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html?tab=readme-ov-file#what-if-i-dont-want-to-allow-any-tags).

Answer (score 1):

Also, There is another option. [Dompurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify)

It is simple.

```
// return : '<img src=? />'
const clean = DOMPurify.sanitize('<img src=? onerror="alert('hello')" />');
```

Comment: yeah i know, but in next js when i'm trying to sanitize input which has came from react quill text editor
const sanitizedContent = DOMPurify.sanitize(noteContent);
      console.log("inside sanitize");
      console.log(sanitizedContent);
like this:
i'm entering: <img src=? onerror="alert('hello')" />
and insted of: <img src=? />
it returns:
<p>&lt;img src=? onerror="alert('hello')" /&gt;</p>